# Phonegap resolveLocalFileSystemURI call after navigator.camera.getPicture

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Phonegap camera API for my android application. 
First I call `navigator.camera.getPicture` method and collects the File_URI. Then I call `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI` method to get the information of image file.

The behavior of second call is a bit strange. For some files it works fine and returns the file info but for other files it gets crashed, without even calling the error callback.

The following are the two error messages I extracted through debugging:

```
processMessage failed: Message: S01 Camera1800268689 scontent://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A2015

processMessage failed: Error: Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

I couldn't figured out what the issue is. Is this related to permission Or limitation of FILE_URI scheme camera API returns or Phonegap File API limitation Or else? 
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.9.

Comment: Can you confirm that through Camera API we can access any image file present on device?